# Call a DoubleClick Bid Manager API

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api-dotnet-client, double-click-advertising

I am writing my first Google APIs Winforms application and I'm unable to figure out how to make an API call.

The example in this google "get started" [documentation](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/getting-started?hl=en) is not helping a lot.

I have a Client ID and secret and have authorized my app using these.

```
ClientSecrets cs = new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "<...>.apps.googleusercontent.com", ClientSecret = "<...>" };

var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(cs, new[] { @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager" }, "user", 
            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, new Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore(@"C:\temp", true));
```

I now want to call [this](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems) API and see its results.

Can someone give me pointers on how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the nugget package [Install-Package Google.Apis.Doubleclickbidmanager.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Doubleclickbidmanager.v1/)

The following code should work for Oauth2

```
string clientId = "ddd";
string clientSecret = "ddd";

var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                    , scopes
                                                                                    , "test"
                                                                                    , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                    , new FileDataStore(".",true)).Result;

   var service = new DoubleClickBidManagerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
       {
       HttpClientInitializer = credential,
       ApplicationName = "xyz",    
       });
```

All your calls should go though the service

```
service.Lineitems.Downloadlineitems(body).Execute();
```

Comment: Hi @DalmTo, thanks for your answer. Can you please point me to some documentation of the DoubleClickBidManagerService and its APIs, so that I can really understand how do I make all the API calls I need.

Or If you have some sample code, which you can share, that does basic upload and download of lineitems, that would be great!! Thanks a lot...

Comment: I can't really I don't know of any and I don't have a double click account so can't write you a tutorial sorry.

Comment: No Problem.. I really appreciate your help.